# body.req is not receiving POST parameters event with bodyparser. It is not working in browser, but working in POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework

```
SERVER.js

var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var expressJWT=require("express-jwt");
var jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
var morgan=require("morgan");
var methodOverride=require("method-override");
var passport=require("passport");

require("./config/database");
require("./config/passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:"application/json"}));
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
  if(err)
    console.log(err);
  next();
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8080");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

var routes=require("./config/routes");
routes(app,passport);

require("./config/passport")(passport);
app.listen(8080,function(err,connection){
    console.log("App listening on port 8080");
});
```

nodejs controller

```
var User=require("./../models/user");
var Token=require("./../shared/getToken");
var jwt=require("jwt-simple");
var config=require('./../../config/database');

module.exports={
    signup:signup,
    authenticate:authenticate,
    memberinfo:memberinfo
};



function authenticate(req,res){
    // if(err)
    //  console.log(err);
    console.log("in authenticate",req.body);
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password)
    {
        res.json({success: false,msg: 'Blank username or password '});
    }
    else
    {
        User.findOne({username: req.body.username},function(err,user)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log('2');
                throw err;
            }
            if(!user)
            {
                console.log('3');
                return res.status(403).send({success: false,msg: 'Authentication failed.User not found'});
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('4');
                user.comparePassword(req.body.password,function(err,isMatch)
                {
                    if(isMatch && !err)
                    {
                        var token=jwt.encode(user,config.secret);
                        res.json({success: true,token: 'JWT '+token});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return res.status(403).send({success: false,msg: 'Authentication failed.Wrong Password'});
                    }

                });
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

angularjs controler from where request is made.

```
$scope.login=function(user){
    console.log(user);
    if(user.username && user.password){
        var url=baseURL+"authenticate";
        $http.post(url,user,{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.status==200){
                if(response.data.success && response.data.token && AuthService.login(response.data.token)){
                    $location.path("/app/dashboard");
                }
            }
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
            if(err.status==401)
                MessageService.showMessage("User does not exist.");
            if(err.status==404)
                MessageService.showMessage("Error Occured.");
        });
    }else{
        MessageService.showMessage("Please provide all fields.");
    }
};
```

I am trying to create a simple mobile app using Ionic Framework with MEAN Stack. But I am facing this problem since 3 days. I am unable to find the solution.The problem is:
When I am making request for authentication with paramters {"username":"something","password":"something"} then req.body in authenticate function is {}. Body parser is already running in server. But this is working fine in POSTMAN but not in browser. what to do ?

Comment: You should look at the Chrome debugger's network tab and see exactly what your Javascript code is sending to the server.  Probably, it is not sending the same thing as when you use Postman and thus it isn't what your server is expecting.

Comment: I saw that. Browser is sending the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You are parsing the body twice. You should remove one of the `bodyParser.json` middlewares.

2- You should serialize the data before sending your request (user=myuser&password=mypassword):

```
var seralize = function serialize (obj) { 
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
    }).join('&');
}

$http.post(url, seralize(user), { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
```

Using `jQuery.param`:

```
var data = $.param({
                user: user.username,
                password: user.password
            });

$http.post(url, data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
```

Using [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike):

```
$http.post(url, $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data), {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} })
```

Or you can let `$http` serialize your data as JSON removing the headers from your request. By default, the `$http` service will transform the outgoing request by serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content type "application/json":

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: user
});
```